# Detect support for @page with Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, css, feature-detection

I need to determine whether a browser supports CSS' `@page` rule or not...

I first thought that I may be able to do this easily with CSS' `@supports()` rule. But my understanding now is that you cannot nest one rule in another and are only able to check the support of classic property/ value declarations.

Now I am trying to use vanilla JS to detect support:

```js
if ('CSS' in window && CSS.supports('@page')) { ... }
```

However, this always returns `false` regardless of browser support.

Does anyone know an alternative way that I can accurately test client support for CSS' `@page` using vanilla JS?

TY.

Comment: How about checking if `CSSPageRule` exists via javascript.  Or something along those lines... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSPageRule

Comment: I looked at `CSSPageRule` prior to posting this question, but unfortunately, it is misleading—`CSSPageRule` is actually supported by Safari and Mobile Safari, even though `@page` is not, so they don't seem to be correlated...